# Properties of spectra

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

I've been trying to understand spectra better, and I was wondering what would be a good source to learn from.  My issue with the classical treatments (e.g., Adams, Switzer) is that people keep telling me that their methods are outdated, while I find the more recent texts (e.g., EKMM, Schwede on symmetric spectra) a little too technical for a novice in this area - I don't think I need to know detailed explicit constructions at this point.

I'm hoping to pick up whatever I need (and also the motivation to tackle some of the more technical texts) by seeing spectra "in action".  But I often stumble because papers and notes often quote some fact about spectra that I did not previously know.  What I would really like is a list of properties of spectra and constructions involving spectra that possibly characterize them, like the axioms for homology or cohomology.  I'm particularly interested in the smash product and its basic and homotopical properties.  The explanation should not need to invoke specific models of spectra, though proofs of course can be deferred to a time when I understand these foundations.

Failing that, a companion guide on how to read a book like Adams' would also be immensely helpful.  I don't know exactly which parts of the book I should skip and what to replace them with.  I also don't know which definitions and techniques have become obsolete.  (If this list is short enough, I guess you can post it in an answer.)

Of course, if you believe that I'm going about all this the wrong way, and that I should just read all of Adams without prejudice or that I should persevere with say, Schwede's book project, please let me know!

Comment: I found this file (https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~cmalkiew/stable.pdf) to be quite helpful as it starts out listing precisely what properties we care for. That said, I am aware that this questions is now old, and given that I'm facing very similar issues, I'd be very happy to know if perhaps you figured it out by now!

Comment: There's a chapter in Rudyak's book *On Thom spectra...* that expands on Adams' exposition, which I had found reassuring.

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna take look at it soon.